# Regex to match string literal

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm currently writing my own language and have a few different types of string literals, that use 3 different symbols to represent them. They are below.

1) `"Hello"` is a simple string literal that is compiled as `Hello`.

2) `'Hello'` is a compressed string that accesses the string compression function. (This returns gibberish)

3) `` `Hello` `` returns a number constructed from each characters code points

I am trying to use regex to match a piece of code like

```
`Hel"lo` 2* "Hel`lo"
```

but can't come up with one that only matches when the first and last characters are the same. I have currently got

```
[`'\"]([\s\S]+|[^`'\"]+)['`\"]
```

but this doesn't produce the result I want.

The expected result for the example should be

```
['`Hel"lo`', ' ', '2', '*', ' ', '"Hel`lo"']
```

but my regex returns

```
['`Hel"lo` 2* "Hel`lo"']
```

In case you couldn't guess, I am kinda inexperienced at regex and so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I assume this is the same in pythons regex engine, but in general regular expressions, you can group a section with parenthesis and reference that match later in the expression using `\N` where `N` is the group number. So something like `([\'\"]).*\1` would match `"test"` but not `"test'` because the end doesn't have the same match as the first group.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing It needs to be captured by a capturing group so you can do `\1` to match the same character matched by that capturing group

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I've tried `re.findall` in Python on that regex and `"test"` but it just returns `['"']` (it only matches the first character)

Comment: That's probably because there is no parenthesis around the `.*`. It will still return the quote because it is part of a group (necessary for matching the quote later with `\1`).

Comment: Try something like this: `([\`'\"]?)([\s\S]+?)\1`. That appears to me to give the same result you are looking for, but I don't use python so it might be wrong. If it works, I can post an answer and describe the changes better. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7AoUoo/2)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: Really, it is impossible to provide a correct answer as the requirements are not clear. If you just want to get the contents between the first delimiter and the closest identical trailing delimiter, use [`[x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(r"([\"'\`])(.*?)\1", s)]`](http://ideone.com/SWSxpo).

Comment: So, did any solution work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If I remember correctly (this was 2 years ago), I developed my own regex that worked. Thanks for the answer tho, I believe it helped

Comment: It would be helpful for future visitors if you either posted a solution, or accepted some answer that worked best for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the contents between the first delimiter and the closest identical trailing delimiter,  you may use

```
import re
s = """`Hel"lo` 2* "Hel`lo\""""
print([x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(r"([\"'`])(.*?)\1", s)])
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/SWSxpo)

**Details**:

- `` ([\"'`]) `` - Group 1 matching a double, single quote or a backtick
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of
- `\1` - the same value as kept in Group 1 (`\1` is  a backreference to Group 1 value).

Answer (score 1):

Using a capture group isn't necessary, you can simply write your pattern like this:

```
`[^`]*`|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\w+|\s+|[^`"'\s\w]
```

One alternative per quote.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/JaSZxw/2)

Comment: You have to escape the `"` but it seems to work otherwise

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: if you use `'''` to enclose your pattern string,  you don't have to escape anything.

Comment: I down voted this because this captures things it should not.  The demo has 6 matches against the original string.  It does indeed match the first string enclosed in `` as well as the second string in "".  But it also matches each blank OUTSIDE the quotes and also the 2 and * each as individual matches.  So, if one wants to match strings (say in a block of code per the OP) this will not get you the desired results.

Comment: @Shane: *"But it also matches each blank OUTSIDE the quotes and also the 2 and * each as individual matches."*: read the question entirely and you will see that my pattern gives the expected result (explicitly written in the question). I didn't add `|\w+|\s+|[^\`"'\s\w]` by fancy.

Comment: @casimir-et-hippolyte somehow I'm missing that in the OP but happy to remove the downvote - I think you need to make an edit though :(

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) this handles for multiline and escaped quotes:

```
([\"'`])(?:[\s\S])*?(?:(?<!\\)\1)
```

I tested and am using this in Javascript, but it works in Python as is:

[Python Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JaSZxw/6)

[Javascript Demo](https://regexr.com/4i9f5)

Comment: I had incorrectly linked the wrong Python demo, its fixed now.